# Why is my query suboptimal?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, innodb

I have a MySQL InnoDB database accessed from a Django server. I have this table:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| areasymbol   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| spatialver   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lkey         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| musym        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| mukey        | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| featsym      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| featkey      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| north        | double       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| south        | double       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| east         | double       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| west         | double       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| soil_type_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The table currently contains ~7-8 million rows, and I expect it'll have at LEAST 3 times that many when I'm done. It's a static table. We do imports to add things to it every once in a while, but nothing gets modified or deleted.

```
+-----------------+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table           | Non_unique | Key_name                         | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| soil_soilregion |          0 | PRIMARY                          |            1 | id           | A         |     7657769 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| soil_soilregion |          1 | soil_soilregion_e733fdfc         |            1 | soil_type_id | A         |          15 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| soil_soilregion |          1 | north_soilregion                 |            1 | north        | A         |     7657769 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| soil_soilregion |          1 | south_soilregion                 |            1 | south        | A         |     7657769 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| soil_soilregion |          1 | east_soilregion                  |            1 | east         | A         |     7657769 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| soil_soilregion |          1 | west_soilregion                  |            1 | west         | A         |     7657769 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| soil_soilregion |          1 | north_south_east_west_soilregion |            1 | north        | A         |     7657769 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| soil_soilregion |          1 | north_south_east_west_soilregion |            2 | south        | A         |     7657769 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| soil_soilregion |          1 | north_south_east_west_soilregion |            3 | east         | A         |     7657769 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| soil_soilregion |          1 | north_south_east_west_soilregion |            4 | west         | A         |     7657769 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

I have a square box of north/south/east/west coordinates and I'm looking for any of these regions that might overlap that box

When I run this query on the database:

```
select *
from soil_soilregion
where east > -86.8379775155 AND north > 40.3782334957 AND
      south < 40.3817576747 AND west < -86.8240119179;
```

it's taking ~10 seconds which is unacceptable. When I use explain this is what it tells me:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys                                                                                      | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | soil_soilregion | ALL  | north_soilregion,south_soilregion,east_soilregion,west_soilregion,north_south_east_west_soilregion | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 7657769 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

When I run this query on the database:

```
select *
from soil_soilregion
where east > -86.8379775155 AND east < -85.8379775155 AND
      north > 40.3782334957 AND north < 41.3782334957 AND
      south < 40.3817576747 AND south > 39.3817576747 AND
      west < -86.8240119179 AND west > -87.8040119189;
```

It takes more like 6-7 seconds. This is better, but still suboptimal. This code will still work, as no objects are more than 1 tall or wide (so I gave it a max distance in each direction of 1).

I have a few questions:

1. Why is the first query not using the indexes? (I assume it's because there's too many potential items in the range)
2. Why does it never use my composite index? Wouldn't that be the most optimal?
3. Is there anything I can do to improve this query or my indexes?

*Note: Using force index has only had negative effects.*

Thanks!

Edit 1:
As per suggestions, I changed the query to be in the same order as the composite index and this is what I got:

```
explain select * from soil_soilregion  where north > 40.3782334957 AND south < 40.3817576747 AND east > -86.8379775155 AND west < -86.8240119179; 
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys                                                                                      | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | soil_soilregion | ALL  | north_soilregion,south_soilregion,east_soilregion,west_soilregion,north_south_east_west_soilregion | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 7657769 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: you try changing the order of the statements in the where? north, south, east, west?

Comment: @JamieD77 - The optimizer will do nothing different if you reorder the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your query are your inequalities.  Alas, these limit the use of indexes -- at most one inequality per index lookup.

The data structure that you need to solve this is a multi-dimensions index.  In SQL databases, this is usually supplied using GIS extensions, which are documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html).

Without these extensions, you can try arcane cleverness.  I can think of one way around this problem, but it makes both the table and the query a bit more complicated.  Add a new column for east and north, which is an integer:  `easti` and `northi`.  Then, build an index on `easti, northi`.  And, write the query as:

```
select *
from ((select sr.*
       from soil_soilregion sr
       where easti = -86 and northi in (40, 41)
      ) union all
      (select sr.*
       from soil_soilregion sr
       where easti = -85 and northi in (40, 41)
      ) 
     ) sr
where east > -86.8379775155 AND north > 40.3782334957 AND
      south < 40.3817576747 AND west < -86.8240119179;
```

The subquery will get everything in a relatively small box.  This is then filtered by the outer query.  The subquery should use the indexes, so it should be quite fast.

Given the size of what you are looking for, using a fraction of a degree would work even better than a whole degree for the integer conversion.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "Alas, these limit the use of indexes -- at most one inequality per index lookup"

Comment: @Erix . . . A reasonable place to start is the MySQL documentation on multi-column indexes:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-column-indexes.html.

Answer (score 0):

A **short-term, but partial fix** is to have a "covering index".  That is, make an index that has the bounding box, plus the id (and maybe the soil type?).  then do this:

```
SELECT b.*
    FROM (
        SELECT id FROM soilregion
            WHERE east... AND west ... AND ...
         ) AS a
    JOIN soilregion AS b ON b.id = a.id;
```

This is likely to speed up the query because of:

- The index is all that is needed in the subquery
- The index is smaller than the data
- When the subquery is finished, it has a short list of `ids`, which are easily and quickly looked up in the real table (via the `JOIN`).

Some of your **'why' questions**:

- The individual indexes merely eliminate some fraction of the 7M rows (as in "everything east of here").  That does not help much.  Furthermore, when an index is that 'useless', it is not used -- it is faster to simply scan the table.
- The compound index (north-south...) does not do any better.  This is because it starts with a range test on `north` and can't get past that.
- The second attempt 'seemed' to be faster -- this could be because of caching, not because of it being any better.

Solutions?...

**Plan A:  Spatial index** as Gordon mentioned.

**Plan B:  Restructure the data to work with a pseudo-2D indexing method** described in my ["find the nearest pizza parlors"](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng) blog.  A problem:  I have not thought through how to adapt for "overlapping" instead of "nearest".